# Android Back Button weird behavior

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin

Right now my sample app, developed using Xamarin, has 2 pages, one is home page which is displayed to user when opening the app, and second page is used to list all available users in database, managed by SQLite.

My problem is when I'm on second page, it currently display about 5 users, and I want to go back to my home page. In order to do that, I pressed the back button. But it doesn't get back to my home page right away, it get BACK to my current page (the second one), I hit the back button again and again, around 4-5 times, then it went back to the first page.

Why?

I think that when I click the back button, method Finish() will be called right? So the current page is stop and pop out from the stack to get to the previous activity.

Am I right there?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace UserManager.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/showUser")]
    public class ShowUserActivity : ListActivity
    {
        UsersQuery query;
        List<string> userName;
        IEnumerator enumerator;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Create your application here                                   
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();
            query = new UsersQuery();
            userName = new List<string>();
            enumerator = query.GetAllUsers().GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                userName.Add(((UsersDB)enumerator.Current).Name);
            }
            query.Dispose();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            this.ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, userName);
        }

        protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof (UserInformationActivity));
            string name = (string) l.GetItemAtPosition(position);
            int userID = query.GetUser(name).Id;

            intent.PutExtra("userID", userID);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in your first activity, post your code where you are opening another activity

Comment: please update the question and post your first activity